# How to add column elements of a 2D list and return result in a list?

Tags: python, python-3.x

> Write a function that takes a two-dimensional list (list of lists) of
>   numbers as argument and returns a list which includes the sum of each
>   column. Assume that the number of columns in each row is the same.

I know how to traverse a row in a multidimensional list but have been facing problem on how to traverse the column elements of a multidimensional list. I'm just a beginner with python. There's no logic I can come up with using for loop or any of the list manipulation methods. I haven't come across the advance topics of lambda or anything of that sort. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: So you have **nested** lists. Fun fact: you can nest loops.

Answer (score 2):

Transpose and `sum` each column:

```
In [1]: arr = [[1,2,3],
         [4,5,6]]

In [2]: list(map(sum, zip(*arr)))
Out[2]: [5, 7, 9]
```

`zip(*arr)` gives you the columns:

```
In [3]: list(zip(*arr))
Out[3]: [(1, 4), (2, 5), (3, 6)]
```

Then mapping sum on each column gives you the sum for each.

If you prefer a list comp:

```
In [5]: [sum(col) for col in zip(*arr)]
Out[5]: [5, 7, 9]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def _sum_of_columns_sample_(sample_list):
cols = len(sample_list[0])
mylist = []
for c in range(cols):
    column_sum = 0
    for row in sample_list:
        column_sum += row[c]
    mylist.append(column_sum)
return mylist
```

Comment: Please add explanation also.

Answer (score 0):

That's not the most beautiful piece of code I've ever come up with, but it should do the trick. If you would use packages such as `numpy`, things get significantly easier.

```
a = [1,2,3]
b = [4,5,6]
res = []
for i in range(len(a)):
   res.append(a[i] + b[i])
```

Comment: How would you do it then?

Comment: List comprehension plus zip? Oops, there is already an answer with that.

Comment: I think you need to at least create `res` with a list comprehension.

Answer (score 0):

A 2 dimensional list can be expressed a list of lists. That is

```
>>> mylist = [[0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8], [9, 10, 11]]
>>>len(mylist)
```

You can now create a sum using nested for loops. Note that this assumes that there are the same number of elements in each column.

```
mysum = [0, 0, 0, 0]

for i in range(len(mylist)):
    for j in range(len(mylist[0])):
        mysum[i] += mylist[i][j]

print mysum
```

If you want to make it more general (and allow for different sized columns) without having to create an explicit mysum list you can use the following code.

```
mysum = []
for i in range(len(mylist)):
    total = 0
    for j in range(len(mylist[i])):
        total += mylist[i][j]
    mysum.append(total)

print mysum
```